# How to open firebird .fdb file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, firebird, fdb

I want to see and check .fdb file. And I am using VS Code to open it. I installed "DB Explorer For Firebird Databases" for this and file opened. However, the opened file was corrupt. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Firebird database file is a file to be read by the [Firebird database engine](https://www.firebirdsql.org/) and queried using SQL. It is not something to be opened in a text editor, like you did in the screenshot.

The *DB Explorer For Firebird Databases* is a plugin for connecting to a Firebird database server, and executing queries against that server. It is not something for viewing the contents of a FDB file directly.

Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, the *DB Explorer For Firebird Databases* has been broken for a while now, and it seems it is no longer maintained. You can connect to a database, and see the tables it has, but attempting to execute queries or view data will not show any query results, but instead shows a *broken image* icon (the [issue for this bug](https://github.com/mvitlov/vscode-db-explorer-firebird/issues/10) has been open since 2019, so I guess it is unlikely to get fixed).

You may want to consider using something like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) or [FlameRobin](https://github.com/mariuz/flamerobin) to query a Firebird database, but that will still require having a Firebird database server installed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try what you said.

Comment: I use [IbExpert](https://www.ibexpert.net/downloadcenter/) since more than 10 years and it does the job pretty well. DBeaver and flamerobin as mentioned by @Mark are also excellent